# An urn contains one red and one black ball.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

An urn contains one red and one black ball. Each time, a ball is drawn independently at random from the urn, and then returned to the urn along with another ball of the same colour. For example, if the first ball drawn is red, the urn will subsequently contain two red balls and one black ball.

**What is the probability of observing the sequence r,b,b,r,r?**

I believe the probability is as follows:
$1/2$ * $1/3$ * $1/2$ * $2/5$ * $1/2$ = $0.016665$

**What is the probability of observing 3 red and 2 black balls?**
$(5C2) = 10 * 0.016665 = 0.16665$

**What is the probability of observing 7 red and 9 black balls?**
$(1/2) * (2/3) * (3/4) * (4/5) * (5/6) * (6/7) * (7/8) * (1/9) * (2/10) * (3/11) * (4/12) * (5/13) * (6/14) * (7/15) * (8/16) * (9/17) = 0.00000514191$
$(16C2) = 120$
$0.00000514191 * 120 = 0.0006170292$

The last part is wrong, but I do not know why. I got the probability of a single sequence and multiplied it by the number of combinations. I was also wondering if there is a nicer way to solve it...

Comment: I don't follow the second one.   Why shouldn't the sequence be r,r,r,b,b?  Why should that have the same probability as r,b,b,r,r?

Comment: The sequence can be any, it just has to contain 3 red balls and 2 black balls. So, P(r,r,r,b,b) + P(r,b,b,r,r) +... There are 10 such combinations.

Comment: But why do you think all sequences have the same probability?

Comment: Well, a hint was provided that they do. Also, P(r,r,r,b,b) = P(r,b,b,r,r) = P(3 red balls, 2 black balls)

Comment: Yes, I've just convinced myself that they do.  (It's easy to prove, once you try.)

Comment: @saulspatz As soon as you don't simplify your fractions, it becomes obvious.

Comment: @Arthur Exactly.

Comment: @saulspatz If you have a proof of that then I think you should publish it. IMV it is *the real answer* to this question. That it is given as a hint does not satisfy.

Comment: @drhab The denominator is always the number of balls in the bag, so that doesn't depend on the sequence.  The numerator is the number of the ball of the color drawn.  (When you draw the first red ball it's $1$, when you draw the third black ball, it's $3$.)  Thus, the numerator doesn't depend on the sequence, but only on the number of balls of each color.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes I am well aware of that, but what I mean is that you should make this last comment an *answer*. Of course you are free in that.

Answer (score 1):

The number of cominations is not  $_{16}C_2$ it must be $_{16}C_7$

Right?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. It should be $(16C7)$ and so $16!/(7!*9!) = 11440$

$0.00000514191 * 11440 = 0.0588234504$

Comment: I am sorry when I typed my answer your answer wasn't yet shown on my screen, maybe because of a connection error

Comment: Yes, it must have been, or maybe it takes a bit to upload the actual answer. But I do appreciate your help!